# Is it possible to check if a graphics device is available without calling dev.new()?

Tags: r, graphics

On a typical Mac installation of R `dev.new()` probably opens a Quartz device. After running `options(device = "X11")`, `dev.new()` would open an XQuartz device (if installed), or return `Error in dev.new() : device 'X11' not found` otherwise.

Is there a way to check if XQuartz is installed and available?

**Edit:** it seems that running `dev.new()` after calling `options(device = "X11")` when XQuartz is *not installed* actually hangs the R session. It does not throw an error. Strangely, if XQuartz is installed while that `dev.new()` call is busy, it will open the device!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way would be to check for the graphics capabilities to see if the function `quartz()` works, which depends on XQuartz being present and shows up in `capabilities()` as aqua, and whether aqua in `capabilities()` is listed as TRUE.

```
any(names(capabilities())  == "aqua" & capabilities() == TRUE)
```

Comment: You could use `isTRUE(unname(capabilities("aqua")))` for the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. `capabilities()` seems to work as expected with XQuartz installed, but is hanging the R session when XQuartz is not installed, instead of just returning `FALSE`... I was on a slightly out of date R version, so I'm going to try and confirm the behaviour in the latest release or R-devel

Comment: Confirmed the problem in R 3.3.0 and R-patched... the difficulty appears to be in `.Internal(capabilitiesX11())` which is called by `capabilities()`

Comment: @MarkO'Connell I am troubleshooting the same problem. Can you elaborate? Is there any way to run R 3.3.0 without encountering this error?

Comment: @adnbps Sorry, I'm afraid I resorted to a nasty check if the user has XQuartz or X11 binary in the usual place on their system. I imagine the problem with `capabilities()` is actually a bug in R, and could be fixed with a timeout on the attempts to find XQuartz. but I did not take the time to confirm this.